# view and Content:user issue

Tags: views, users

while customizing front page i can not find 'Content: User' to add author name field in views. but i can find something like `Content: Author uid` how to show author name in front page?
another question i cant add new fields while selecting grid view, how to fix it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Unformatted list format used by default from the front page view, you would see the author of the node. This happens if you selected *Display author and date information* on the settings page for the content type (admin/structure/types/manage/[content type]).

[image: screenshot]

Supposing that you change the format to, for example, *Table* (which allows you to add fields), when you add the new fields you will notice that *Content: Author uid* field has the following description:

> The user authoring the content. If you need more fields than the uid add the content: author relationship.

So, you just add a relationship.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Once you do that, you will find the author name between the fields you can add.

[image: screenshot]

As for the *Grid* format, it doesn't uses fields; that is why you cannot select them.

[image: screenshot]